# jsplumb - how to make connector fixed?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

As this png, the connector is at "BOTTOM", and if I move the box to left, the connector moved to "LEFT" too(as the 2nd png).
[image]

[image]

But I want the connector to fixed at "BOTTOM", how to do?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is due to the anchor you're using

https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/lib/anchors

You want to use 'Bottom' for a fixed anchor on the bottom edge.